# Python Pandas: detecting existence of timestamp in Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to detect if a timestamp in the series, but it returns false even if it exists. Can someone help me find out why this doesn't work?

```
In [149]: results.index[1] in time_range[0]
Out[149]: False

In [150]: results.index[1]
Out[150]: Timestamp('2013-07-05 00:00:00')

In [151]: time_range[0][19]
Out[151]: Timestamp('2013-07-05 00:00:00')

In [152]: type(time_range[0][19])
Out[152]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

In [153]: type(results.index[1])
Out[153]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

In [154]: type(time_range[0])
Out[154]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.isin` operator for `pd.Series.index`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ser = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), index=pd.date_range('2013-07-05 00:00:00', periods=10, freq='D'))

2013-07-05   -1.1967
2013-07-06    0.2598
2013-07-07   -0.0319
2013-07-08   -0.7489
2013-07-09   -0.3605
2013-07-10    0.0354
2013-07-11    0.5557
2013-07-12   -1.9588
2013-07-13    1.4929
2013-07-14    1.3351
Freq: D, dtype: float64


time_range = [pd.Timestamp('2013-07-05'), pd.Timestamp('2013-07-07')]

ser.index.isin(time_range)

array([ True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! It works! In case of I have just one timestamp to be detected, is there any better solutions than transforming this single timestamp in to a Series?

Comment: @Jim if you just want to detect one timestamp, the standard `in` should work `pd.Timestamp('2013-07-05') in time_range` returns `True`.

Comment: It's little bit weird it still doesn't work. I think it might because the way I construct time_range isn't quite right. Anyway thanks a lot! Fei Chang Gan Xie! Good luck on your job seeking!

Comment: @Jim :-) You are most welcome. Glad that it helped. Bu Ke Qi!